# PHP: How to add attributes to the deeper child note with SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, php-5.4

How can I add attributes to the deeper child note with `SimpleXMLElement`? for instance,

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

$response = $xml->addChild('response');
$response->addChild('error');
$response->addAttribute('elementid', 100);
$response->addAttribute('message', 'You must not leave this field empty!');


Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

I get this,

```
<xml>
<response elementid="100" message="Key name - You must not leave this field empty!">
<error />
</response>
</xml>
```

But actually I want,

```
<xml>
<response>
<error elementid="100" message="Key name - You must not leave this field empty!" />
</response>
</xml>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

$response   = $xml->addChild('response');
$error      = $response->addChild('error');
$error->addAttribute('elementid', 100);
$error->addAttribute('message', 'You must not leave this field empty!');

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

Comment: Is it clear what was wrong? I think the code is pretty clear in pointing out were it went wrong, right?

Comment: yes it is clear. Now I see what was wrong. thank you very much!